# A2DP bluetooth device on win7 develops massive latency after a couple hours

Tags: windows, audio, bluetooth, a2dp

I have no idea what to pin this on, and I'm going a little nuts ...

I have these A2DP speakers: [http://www.amazon.com/Logitech-Wireless-USB-Speaker-Z515/dp/B003VAHYXW](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003VAHYXW)

they're great. I got a deal on them and they didn't come with the USB receiver, but I figured, hey, I have a cheap bluetooth dongle, no big deal.

They work fine (with a few ms of latency) right after being paired/installed, but after giving them a rest for a little while (i.e. waiting a couple hours without playing any audio, or letting the machine suspend, etc.) when I try to use them again, there's about 5-10 seconds of latency on the audio (this gets pretty ridiculous pretty quickly), and there's nothing I can do to fix this other than unpair, restart the machine, and re-pair. I've tried newer CSR drivers, I've tried restarting the Windows Audio and BT services; nothing fixes this apart from re-starting and re-pairing.

I have a suspicion that I just have a junky BT dongle, but I used to have an even junkier one that had issues with re-pairing a headset after I'd shut it off; this one has no problem with the headset, just massive A2DP latency. Are there entire tiers of "crappy bluetooth dongle" that I'm currently slowly climbing through, or am I missing some easy software solution?

Comment: It is most likely your BT dongle... Windows support (even in 8) still sucks for audio devices especially bluetooth. I have had many problems with bluetooth and this is one of them. It more often than not is related to the dongle than the device. Buy a high rated known-name brand adapter.

Comment: thanks. I think I've actually figured out a reproducible set of steps for fixing them without restarting (it involves unplugging the dongle, restarting services, then plugging it back in) ... will let you know. I got this one in a two pack and put the other in my Ubuntu machine; will see if they have the same issues.

Answer (score 3):

well, confirmed I can fix it by turning the speaker off, re-plugging the dongle and then running:

```
net stop hfgservice
net start hfgservice
net stop audiosrv
net stop audioendpointbuilder
net start audioendpointbuilder
net start audiosrv
```

then turning the speaker back on. needless to say, this is a bit tedious (though having the BT dongle in a front USB port within arm's reach helps), and I ought to finally get a more expensive dongle so this isn't necessary.

Comment: Hi, hope you can still read and answer this. Have you ever solved this without unplugging? Does buying a better dongle solve this issue?